# Make known subclassed wigets in .ui files in GTK+

Tags: widget, gtk, subclass, glade

I was looking in the GNOME Calendar application, and the `gcal-window.ui` file has this line (on 292) in it:

```
<object class="GcalQuickAddPopover" id="quick_add_popover">
```

And in the same directory that the `gcal-window` ui, source code, and header files were in, there is the file that defines the `GcalQuickAddPopover`. What are the rules for making the `.ui` files knowing which object are in existence, and which are not. If I deleted the gcal-quick-add-popover file, how would it know or not know that it is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types that can be used inside a [GtkBuilder UI definition](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Builder.html#a-gtkbuilder-ui-definition) are the ones registered at **run-time** before the XML is parsed (typically by calling `gtk_builder_new` or similar).

Here is a self-contained example that shows that.

```
/* cc ui.c -o ui $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>


/* Define new type (MyCustomLabel) */

#define MY_TYPE_CUSTOM_LABEL my_custom_label_get_type()
struct _MyCustomLabel { GtkLabel label; };

G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE(MyCustomLabel, my_custom_label, MY, CUSTOM_LABEL, GtkLabel)
G_DEFINE_TYPE(MyCustomLabel, my_custom_label, GTK_TYPE_LABEL)

static void
my_custom_label_class_init(MyCustomLabelClass *cls)
{
}

static void
my_custom_label_init(MyCustomLabel *label)
{
    gtk_label_set_label(GTK_LABEL(label), "This is my custom label");
}


/* Test case */

static const gchar *ui =
    "<interface>"
        "<object id='W' class='GtkWindow'>"
            "<child>"
                "<object class='MyCustomLabel'/>"
            "</child>"
        "</object>"
    "</interface>";


int main()
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    /* Ensures that MyCustomLabel has been registered with the type
     * system. Without this call, the application crashes when parsing
     * `ui`, i.e. at the `gtk_builder_new_from_string` call. */
    g_type_ensure(MY_TYPE_CUSTOM_LABEL);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_string(ui, -1);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "W"));
    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

See the [GObject documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/concepts.html) for more details on how the type system works.